# IEEETran section heading all uppercase letters

Tags: sectioning, ieeetran, ieee-style

How can I make the section heading look like this (centered, small caps and Roman numerals):

[image]

I am preparing a paper for IEEE Percom conference (http://www.percom.org/?q=home). I am using

```
\documentclass[conference, compsoc]{IEEEtran}
```

and

```
\section{Introduction}.
```

It produces:

1. Introduction

Also, am I using the right document class for the IEEE conference?

Comment: By "this" you actually mean (1) centered, (2) small caps and (3) Roman numerals?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not mentioning before. This is my first post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get centered/small-caps/Roman-numbered section headers, you need to fix one of the `\documentclass` options: The option needs to be given as `comsoc`, not `compsoc`. Aside: It's maybe a bit unfortunate/confusing that the "IEEE Communications Society" (aka `comsoc`) and the "IEEE Computer Society" (aka compsoc) have very similar abbreviated names. :-(

A small MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[comsoc,conference]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} 
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just changing the conference from "compsoc" to "comsoc" worked. But I was wondering as this is a computer society conference, is it the right thing to do? Also thanks for the MWE :-)

Comment: @Osmani - Well, "percom" is short for "Pervasive computing and communications" -- both "computing" *and* "communications" are in the title! However, if you want the section headers to be centered, set in small caps, and Roman-numbered, you need to use the `comsoc` option.